# change the ContentPlaceHolder's ID

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, contentplaceholder

I have a master page. in this master page I have a content place holder with `id="ContentPlaceHolder1"`
I changed this to `id="main-content"` then change the ContentPlaceHolderID of any content page that created with this master page
but I have an error:

> 'main-content' is not a valid identifier.

what should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not use "-" in your ID. you can use

> **main_content**

or

> **maincontent**